# Can I "hide" composition during property access in PHP?

Tags: php

I write a `Model` class in PHP and this class has a `$db` property to store a database class object.

When I derive my class from `Model` class, if I want to access to `$db` object I must do this:

```
class post extends Model
{
    function a()
    {
       return $this->db->find();
       // .....
    }
}
```

But I want to gain direct access to the database object in the `post` class, like this:

```
class post extends Model
{
    function a()
    {
       return $this->find();
       // .....
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please take greater care over your posts. And I don't see the relevance of inheritance to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to declare a find function in your class:

```
function find(){
     return $this->db->find();
}
```

Comment: thanks.my database class many function and i want to access all functions and property directly.are there dynamic way to this problem?

Comment: @Mr-Moqadam: Why don't you use your database class directly if it already has all you need?

Comment: you could make your class inherit the DB class, but i wouldn't recommend it. whats wrong with using it as intended?

Comment: As far as i can tell, you are already doing it the right way. If you want to access stuff without directly interfacing the DB class, you should implement getters/setters for each thing you want. That ends up being a lot of work, so many people use an ORM or framework that takes of all this for them. I like Symfony

Comment: I think it might not be best to reinvent the wheel here, especially if you aren't sure how to make getter/setter functions.

Comment: @Mr-Moqadam: You can always read the Symfony / Doctrine source-code which is publicly available to learn some ways how something could be done. And then write it yourself if you want to do it on your own.

Comment: All the source of symfony / doctrine is now on github, you can grab the source, edit it, contribute features is you need, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you start with "has".

You already have the db while you want something different, it's sort of a line-up in the wrong way:

```
you -> db -> model
```

But you want the model first, then the db:

```
you -> model -> db
```

So the model can hide the db when you use it.

There are many ways to create something like that, in fact you have already started with it by specifying that you want to have an interface for the model:

```
$model->find();
```

The only thing left is that the model knows where the db is (which already exists). As you have not shown in your question what the `find()` method of the db actually does (and what makes it *different* from the `find()` method of any model), it's hard to suggest a specific way how you create the relationship between any model and the db easily.

But I hope this is helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** There is nothing in PHP to do this for you. It really wouldn't make any sense, as a feature.